# Metadata type_x issue (I want to create a quick Action Dynamically from MetaData API)

Tags: lightning-web-components, metadata-api, quickaction

This is how I am trying to create the quickAction.

```apex
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
MetadataService.QuickAction customObject = new MetadataService.QuickAction();
customObject.targetObject = 'Test__c';
customObject.lightningWebComponent = 'uploadWordDocument';
customObject.actionSubtype = 'ScreenAction';
customObject.label = 'testButton 123';
customObject.fullName = 'testButton123';
customObject.description = 'Test 123';
customObject.optionsCreateFeedItem = false;
customObject.type =  'QuickAction' ;
customObject.type_x = 'lightningWebComponent';
List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.createMetadata(
                    new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customObject });
handleSaveResults(results[0]);
```

I am getting following error:

> common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: Must specify a {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type attribute value for the {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}metadata element faultcode=soapenv:Client faultactor="|0x33ffe847

Comment: shouldn't `type_x` = `LightningComponent` [per doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickaction.htm?q=quickaction) ?

Comment: I tried that as well, still getting the error @cropredy

Comment: one strategy to follow is to retrieve an existing QuickAction of similar type and debug the values of the properties

Comment: I tried that as well, no success @cropredy